# Getting an signaturedoesntmatch error when I tried to access a image that I uploaded to aws s3 bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vBK9.jpg)
This is the error I'm getting. I'm new to aws and I don't know how things works here. I referred many documentations but noting worked for me. Please give a solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Make sure you add signature version to be s3v4 because the default is not that!

Answer (score 0):

The example that shows how to successfully work with S3 and the AWS SDK for Python is found in this Github repo.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/python/example_code/s3

The Python code example that shows you how to retrieve an object in an Amazon S3 bucket is here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/python/example_code/s3/s3_basics/object_wrapper.py